# xpath - check if element occurs more than once

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to check with xpath if an element occurs more than once.

XML:

```
<XML>
    <containers>
        <container id="1">
        </container>
        <container id="2">
        </container>
    </containers>
</XML>
```

I tried it with the following simple xpath expression

```
$xml->xpath('/XML/containers/container');
```

I got:

```
Element='<container id="1">
        </container>'
Element='<container id="2">
        </container>'
```

But as a result I want something like an array that is like

```
$containers = array('container', 'container');
```

How can I archive that?

Comment: In XPath - you could use `count(/XML/containers/container)`, but unfortunately SimpleXML doesn't support this type of expression (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an array to check the number of matches. Just `count()` the result of the XPath, that will give you your number:

```
$a = '<XML>
<containers>
    <container id="1">
    </container>
    <container id="2">
    </container>
</containers>
</XML>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($a);
$containers = $xml->xpath('/XML/containers/container');
$totalContainers = count($containers); // 2
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ClXdh)